# Why is this lambda function with df.assign not working row-wise as expected?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, assign

I have a dataframe and want to get the idxmin of a values column, but for each ID (which can occure multiple times).
My df:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [123, 122,122,122,123,125,126],
                     'values':[ 2, 1, 2, 8, 6, 4, 5]})
```

No I would use a lambda function, filter the df to get a subselected df for all ID occurences and use idxmin to get the min index value of that subselect. When I use the different parts alone, they work as intended, but when I use it together, it just outputs the same ID (overall idxmin) for every row.

```
data.assign(TEST = lambda x: data.loc[data["ID"]==x["ID"],"values"].idxmin())
```

Output:

| Index | ID | values | TEST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 123 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 122 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 122 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 122 | 8 | 1 |
| 4 | 123 | 6 | 1 |
| 5 | 125 | 4 | 1 |
| 6 | 126 | 5 | 1 |

Does anybody know why the behaviour is like that instead of:

| Index | ID | values | TEST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 123 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 122 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 122 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 122 | 8 | 1 |
| 4 | 123 | 6 | 0 |
| 5 | 125 | 4 | 5 |
| 6 | 126 | 5 | 6 |

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `assign`, `x` is the full dataframe, thus

```
data.loc[data["ID"]==data["ID"],"values"].idxmin()
```

returns `1`, and your code is equivalent to:

```
data.assign(TEST=1)
```

You need to use `groupby` here:

```
data['TEST'] = data.groupby('ID')['values'].transform('idxmin')
```

output:

```
    ID  values  TEST
0  123       2     0
1  122       1     1
2  122       2     1
3  122       8     1
4  123       6     0
5  125       4     5
6  126       5     6
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! That's what I was looking for. But do you also know why the lambda isnt't working here?

Comment: @marvinhooo yes, I already updated the answer ;)